# Windows 10 grub problem

Tags: boot, grub2

In my Dell notebook I had installed Windows 10. When I installed Ubuntu 17.04, I can't run Windows from Ubuntu grub/that violet window/. It shows that I have Windows 10 in last row, but when I choose Win10 it doesn't run, only shows grub after dark screen.
When I installed Ubuntu I chose the first option: Install with windows 10. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: More likely fast start up (hibernation) still on or NTFS needs chkdsk. Is system UEFI and can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Grub only boots working Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the grub points to wrong partition or else your Windows boot files are corrupt / do not exist.

```
sudo os-prober
```

This will show list of another bootable OS installed in the system.

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update the grub and correct the wrong entries.